# annotator.js working locally but not on web server, any ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, annotations

No real code to show you, just a general question.

Annotator.js works fine on my local server, but the second I deploy it, it stops working. Sorry for the lack of specificity, but has anyone experienced anything similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your API server supports CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing), you can quickly check in your browser console.